# VisualBasic- Error of "WriteInteger is not declared"

Tags: vb.net, basic

```
WriteInteger("processname", &H1101AA38, -2)
```

I don't use VisualBasic often but I want to change the value to an address of a process.

I hoped that the line of code would
Go to the processname proecess, go to the address of 1101AA38, then set it's value to -2. BUT, visual studio says "WriteInteger is not declared"

I got WriteInteger from a video and changed the stuff inside the parenthesis to what I need it to be. I'm not quite sure what I should do. Help me out please?

Comment: WriteInteger is not a Windows or VB function. You'll need to supply an implementation or use a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is not Visual Basic. It's probably PureBasic (see [here](http://www.purebasic.com/documentation/file/writeinteger.html)). 
The closest equivalent in Visual Basic is [System.IO.BinaryWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter(v=vs.110).aspx). The example is from MSDN docs.

```
Dim stream As New FileStream("RobloxPlayerBeta", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
Dim writer As New System.IO.BinaryWriter(stream)
Dim i As Integer = -2
Dim offset As Integer = &H1101AA38
stream.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Begin)
writer.Write(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `WriteProcessMemory` check url
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx